# Error when installing Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I recently did an in place upgrade of my Server 2008 R2 Standard VM's to Server 2008 R2 Enterprise via

`Dism /online /Set-Edition:ServerEnterprise /ProductKey:xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx`

as referenced here: [In-place upgrade from Windows Server Standard to Enterprise or Datacenter](https://serverfault.com/questions/34846/in-place-upgrade-from-windows-server-standard-to-enterprise-or-datacenter/226964#226964)

This went well except for now when I want to install SP1 I get the following errors in the CBS.log:

```
2011-02-23 11:58:30, Info                  CBS    SPI: Starting SPInstall version 6.1.7601.17514

2011-02-23 11:58:31, Error                 CBS    SPI: (CheckForPendingFlag:90)Failed to open component hive at C:\Windows\System32\config\components er=0x0

2011-02-23 11:58:31, Error                 CBS    SPI: (CSystem::Initialize:317)Failed to GetProductInfo GLE=0x0

2011-02-23 11:58:31, Error                 CBS    SPI: (wmain:939)Failed to initialize system hr=0x80004005

2011-02-23 11:58:32, Info                  CBS    SPI: SPInstall terminating, return code 0x80004005

2011-02-23 11:58:32, Error                 CBS    SPI: (SPIRegQueryStringValue:700)Failed to query registry value: MiscString2 er=0x2

2011-02-23 11:58:32, Error                 CBS    SPI: (CSystem::GetMachineName:395)Failed to query machine name from RAC hr=0x80070002

2011-02-23 11:58:32, Error                 CBS    SPI: (CCrimsonLogger::Unregister:50)Crimson logger not registered hr=0x8000ffff
```

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any resources on how to fix the Components hive (it exists and has the same permissions as a machine where the install successfully starts).  This happens with the standalone installer as well as the windows update installer.

**update**  switching back to the KMS key allows me to install SP1.  Remains to be seen if RDP will work (another issue that cropped up as a part of this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround last night.  I discovered it had something to do with my original MAK key and its reuse.

The original VM was a Server 2008 R2 VM with an MSDN MAK Key (which is valid for standard and enterprise edition)

I did the DISM upgrade using the "489J6-VHDMP-X63PK-3K798-CPX3Y" KMS key for enterprise (from this post) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/0c68ffd9-ed83-4437-aa79-2f7decc75c0f.

After the DISM upgrade I switched back to my original MAK key (and activated successfully).  A secondary behavior of this was that Remote Desktop was no longer functional on any machine that used the MAK Key.  I then did some additional research and found that other people had experienced the same problem using the DISM upgrade ( http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/6debc586-0977-4731-b418-ca1edb34fe8b ).  On a hunch I switched back to the KMS key and was then able to install SP1 (and remote desktop was reenabled).  I then tried a Std/Enterprise license from a different MSDN account and it activated successfully, as well as kept Remote Desktop enabled.  I also tested switching back to my original MAK key and this worked as well.  I then just switched the rest of my VM's to the new MSDN key and this was successful as well, without re-introducing the KMS key.

Best I can tell, there must be something unique to using the same key at each end of the standard -> enterprise DISM upgrade path.